# The get() method times-out although the page is displayed correctly

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 in Java, and when loading a web page using Webdriver's (the InternetExplorerDriver class) get() method a time-out is received and the execution halts although the page appears as completely loaded to me.
I've tried using the WebDriverWait class but I can't figure out what function to provide as the condition to the until() method .
**Update**: implemented the Condition class, but now can't figure out whether the  wait.until() method should be used before or after the get()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your page have some AJAX so WebDriver thinks that it is loaded, while it is not yet. You should utilize [Page Objects pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [AjaxElementLocatorFactory](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/59b77199ceca4f56/f29355bbdaba6db9?lnk=gst&q=AjaxElementLocatorFactory#f29355bbdaba6db9) - its more reliable then just using `wait`. Also this pattern allows creation of maintainable tests and have many advantages

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  I'll look into the suggestions.

 The issue is that the tested application is NOT the webpage but the iframe that is opened by running some javascript code AFTER the page is loaded, and the webpages used are all different & not proprietary , so I'm wondering how to incorprorate that into the test..

Comment: In this case you still need to wait for objects to be loaded, and using PageFactory is a good way to do so. However you may need to switch to the iframe before initializing your page object

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still don't understand how can I use switch to iframe if the driver.get() is not back yet... Perhaps there is an example for the PageFactory pattern that you described, except the one you'be linked originally? (I can't seem to be able to post any message on Selenium google group as I'm a new user and the moderators' approval seems to never occur :))

Comment: take a look at this - http://zloiadun.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-page-object-pattern-for-web.html